# Tracking the list of created instances

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a person class & I want to keep track of all the person instances created across my application.

```
var people = [];
// My failed attempt
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  create: function(){
     var instance = this._super();
     people.push(instance);
     return instance;
  }
})
```

Is there any hook which gets executed after an Object has been created ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `Ember.Object.init`

```
var people = [];
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function() {
    people.push(this);
  }
});

var sophia = App.Person.create({name: "Sophia"});
var greta = App.Person.create({name: "Greta"});

var names = people.getEach('name');
```

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_init

Comment: How did I forget **init** ?! I need some serious sleep :P Thanks :)